# Can't get anything to stay above image in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well, I tried looking around for a solution, I did try multiple solutions but can't get them to work for my HTML/CSS specifically. I haven't ever done much css or html so I'm fairly new at this.

College project so ignore the pointless crap about Elon Musk and iron man. I hate it too.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
        <style>
        @-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
        }

        .background-image {
        background-image: URL('ironman.jpg');

        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;

        opacity: 0;

        -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;

        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

        .background-image.visible {
        opacity: 1;
        }
        <!-- End of background animation -->
        headerReplacement {
            font-size:40px;
            color:aqua;
            margin-top:-10px;
            margin-bottom:-15px;
            letter-spacing: 20px;
        }
        h1, p, body, html {
           margin:0;
           padding:0;
        }
        body {
           background:#000;
           font:12px verdana, sans-serif;
           color:#000;
        }
        #headerbg {
           background: grey;
           text-align:center;
           padding:20px;
        }
        <!-- End of tag formatting -->
    </style>
    <div class="background-image">
    </div>
    <title>Elon Musk</title>
    <div id="headerbg">
        <h1>Elon Musk</h1>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
    <h12>test</h12>
</body>
</html>
```

What happens is that the image fades in and the title fades because of that. Once the image fades in it is on top of everything, and I can't stop it from doing that.

The stylesheet is for animations to apply to the headers, all the css/html that is in use (by the background) is included in the code above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't diss Iron Man! :(

Comment: What do you want the image to do instead?

Comment: I want the image to do what it's doing, just without the whole 'I'm going to cover everything up and not sit behind everything.'

Comment: So you want it to sit behind everything?

Comment: Do you want the title to come up front? Btw why is your main content markup inside the head tag?

Comment: check this jsfiddle if you want this then let me know http://jsfiddle.net/7Lcvu31q/

Comment: Yes, I want the image to stay behind everything. By 'content markup' I assume you mean the CSS and almost all the code? We were told to put all CSS in the head for our website as it loads before things are displayed on the webpage.

Comment: it's all about z-index and position. try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EapoLZ

Comment: Content markup is the divs those needs to be inside the body tag, also there is no such tag as h12 it is either h1 or h2.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this before but it didnt' work, obviously I'm a bit stupid or something. Thanks for the help. h12 - This was a mistake, I was trying so many things I lost track. Thanks.

Comment: This question should not be down voted as he has tried to do something that hasn't worked so it is a valid question. we are here to help. good luck @Forensik and don't stop learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add z-index to your code in order to put that div behind of all elements

```
background-image {
    ...your code
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: This is what @fahad.kazi has done, wierdly I tried the whole z-index thing to solve this, but it didn't work. I assume I was being stupid and put it somewhere wrong. Thanks all of you for helping. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a z-index in this class

```
 .background-image {
    background-image: URL('ironman.jpg');

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
```

Also add z-index in this class

```
    #headerbg {
       background: grey;
       text-align:center;
       padding:20px;
       position:relative;
       z-index:1;
    }
```

This markup will be in body tag

```
<body>
<div class="background-image">
</div>
<div id="headerbg">
    <h1>Elon Musk</h1>
</div>
</body>
```